# Defining new subsubsection not working

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have defined a new numbering system for sections and subsections as shown below:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

If I then try to add:

```
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

This doesn't work and I can't understand why when it's exactly the same as the others!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should mention what "doesn't work". And you should make a *complete* example – e.g. the document class certainly matters.

Comment: Perhaps in your document class `\thesubsubsection` is not defined and so you can't use `\renewcommand`. Use `\newcommand` or `\def` instead. But to know for sure you need to at least provide the exact error message.

Comment: I tried with just \newcommand but that produces 'thesubsubsection already defined'. I didn't provide an error with the \renewcommand since there isn't one. It just doesn't show the numbers for each subsubsection.

Comment: Use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! That works =) The only thing now is how do I include these subsubsections in the contents table?

Comment: `\setcounter{tocnumdepth}{3}`.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it out but it's actually \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} and not 'tocnumdepth'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer, just providing the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{%
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection A}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B}
\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

The only problem I can see is the narrow distance between the section number and the section title in the table of contents because of the added `.0`.

**Refinement**. From the comments it seems the default for counter `secnumdepth` is two,
then the class is probably not `article` but `report` or `book` or similar.

New Example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{%
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter X}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\subsection{Subsection B}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection A}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection B}
\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE2]